# Javascript: for vs jQuery.each() with time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Figure 1

```
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do something with Things[i]
    }, 200 * i);
};
```

Figure 2

```
$(".things").each(function(i,o){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //do something with o
    }, 200 * i);
});
```

Why does figure 2 work but figure 1 doesn't? Every time I try the first method `i` always equals `-1`. What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
          // do something with Things[i]
        }, 200 * i);
    })(i)
};
```

You need to create a scope for `i`, so it maintains its value. Otherwise it gets updated with the loop.

The reason it works for figure 2 (`$.each(function(i,o){...})`) is because the anonymous function here is creating a closure for `i`.

Comment: I assume this would not work in a case where `i` would be a reference ? the i accessed in setTimeout references the i from the closure's scope right ? What if you modify i within this scope, does it also modify the i from the upper scope ? Wouldn't it be a good idea to give it a different name ?

Comment: @Virus721 - No the `i` passed through becomes completely separate from the upper scope. You can do what you like with it and it wouldn't modify the looping variable `i`. You could give it a different name if you like, but it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Although this is a correct statement, it's not an answer to his question.  This does not explain why i is -1.

Comment: I wonder something. Isn't this just shifting the problem ? i mean, whether you create a closure a pass "i" to it or you pass "i" to setTimeout, in both cases the i is copied to a different scope. In your solution the i is copied to the closure's scope, and without the closure, the i is copied to the setTimeout's scope, right ?

Comment: @Archer - The loop wouldn't actually run in the first instance if `Things` didn't have at least one item. The condition would fail.

Comment: @Virus721 - Nope. The `i` doesn't get passed as an argument to the `setTimeout`. The reason it works for `$.each(function(i,o){...})` is because the anonymous function here is creating a closure for `i`.

Comment: @ahren Of course - silly of me.  And now this answer makes perfect sense to me :)  +1

Comment: @ahren, could you edit your answer with the explanation from that last comment please, that's exactly the bit of info I was after

Comment: @arhen Yes but the result of i * 200 is passed to setTimeout so no matter if i is changed at the next loop, a setTimeout will have been called with the right value, right ?

Comment: @Virus721 - no, that's setting the amount of time before the function is executed (in milliseconds). The variable doesn't get passed through to the function at all. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5JJJX/ --- The `200*i` part will always evaluate with the correct `i` value, however *inside* the `setTimeout` anonymous function is where the value would refer to the value of `i` in the upper scope without a closure.

Answer (score 1):

@ahren answer is ok. I got similar thing without IIF, which could be more simple for someone...

```
function loop(i) {
// do something with Things[i]
    if(--i>=0) {
        setTimeout(loop, 200*i, i);
    }
}

setTimeout(loop, 200*Things.length, Things.length);
```