# Apply Delay for jQuery mouseover event Tried hoverintent but i want to do it dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax

Apply Delay for jQuery mouseover event Tried hoverintent but i want to do it dynamically.

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseover', 'span[id^=viewLCmnt_]', function() {
    function ajaxTest();
});
```

i want to add a delay and not trigger other mouse-over before finishing first mouse-over event. Now events are triggering so fast that it is looking odd.

How can i add a delay or just fire a single ajax function on mouse over event.

TRIED LIKE THIS

```
var delay = 1000;
var area = jQuery('span[id^=viewLCmnt_],i[id^=viewLThumb_]');
area.on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    jQuery(this).data( 'mouseIsOver', true );
});
area.on( 'mouseleave', function() {
    jQuery(this).data( 'mouseIsOver', false );
});
area.on( 'mouseover', function() {
    setTImeout( function() {
        if( area.data( 'mouseIsOver' ) ) {
            area.trigger( 'mouseoverdelay' );
        }
    }, delay );
});
area.on( 'mouseoverdelay', function() {
    lv(jQuery(this), jQuery('#site').val());
});
```

SOLVED BY BELOW CODE:

```
var timer;
jQuery("body").on("mouseenter", "span[id^=viewLCmnt_],i[id^=viewLThumb_]", function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        lv(jQuery(this), jQuery('#site').val());
    }, 2000);
}).on("mouseleave", "span[id^=viewLCmnt_],i[id^=viewLThumb_]", function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var delay = 1000;

$( ... ).on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        var $area = $(this);
        $area.data( 'mouseIsOver', true );
        // Create a scope for async problems.
        (function( $areaRef ) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                if( $areaRef .data( 'mouseIsOver' ) ) {
                    $areaRef .trigger( 'mouseoverdelay' );
                }
            }, delay );
        })( $area );
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        $(this).data( 'mouseIsOver', false );
    },
    mouseoverdelay : function() {
       // Your stuff
    }
});
```

PS : Didn't test this.

Comment: my selector is dynamic one like span[id^=viewLCmnt_].. i have updated the question.

Comment: @GeorgeJoffinJoy See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837753/javascript-for-vs-jquery-each-with-time-delay/19837797#comment29499936_19837797 for the problems due to the asyncchronousness of functions like setTimeout.

Comment: what does $areaRef do ?

Comment: See my comment above. I'm not sure you would get this kind of problems in your case, but if you do, this is needed.

Comment: thanks for quick response... but event is not getting triggered on "mouseenter" for area = 'span[id^=viewLCmnt_],i[id^=viewLThumb_]'; ??? any idea why it is not triggering

Comment: First make sure your selector actually selects something (alert .length for example), and then make sure things are well spelled. I havn't tested this code, just giving you an idea about how to do it. And if your element is dynamically created, you should have a look to `.delegate()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: There are two way to use .on, one of these two replaces .delegate.

Comment: thanks i solved the problem with second option i tried...and updated the answer in question itself.